# Bind duplicate rows in Dataset once

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am merging two datasets and I wish that duplicate rows are only bind once ,how can I achieve this ?

```
 protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    showRelatedcat();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataSet ds_frd = new DataSet();
    String frdQuery = my query
    String newquery = my other query 
    String queryString = another one 
    try
    {
        // Connect to the database and run the query.
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(newquery, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(frdQuery, connection);
        // Fill the DataSet.
        adapter1.Fill(ds_frd);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        ds.Merge(ds_frd, true);
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        // The connection failed. Display an error message.
        //Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database.";

    }



    RadGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].;


}
```

both queries have some rows as common .

Comment: Do both datasets contain only one table?

Comment: Can't you just refactor frdQuery + newquery  to a single query and let the database handle the distinct(). Seems more efficient to me?

Answer (score 0):

you can merge dataset using Dataset.Merge using IEnumerable function
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/ebe7e4c2-2cad-4a9d-9134-2732d1e05664
it allows you to get only one value in duplicate case